# Refactoring if-else if - else

Tags: c#, design-patterns, if-statement, refactoring, solid-principles

I have the following code example

```
if(object.Time > 0 && <= 499)
{
     rate = .75m
}
else if(object.Time >= 500 && <= 999)
{
     rate = .85m
}
else if(object.Time >= 1000)
{
     rate = 1.00m
}
else
{
     rate = 0m;
}
```

My question is what design pattern can I use to make this better?

Edit: Just to clarify a little better, the code you see here is something that currently exists within a Strategy Pattern Implementation. We have 3 types of calculations 2 of which has 3 different "rates" that could be used based off of the time you see below. I thought about creating a strategy implementation for each rate, but then I would be moving the logic for determining the strategy to use and make that a mess as well.

Thanks!

Comment: @SriramSakthivel You can clearly tell that this is mock code, ight?

Comment: Some people prefer using case statements for things like this but I dont think either is really better.

Comment: @It'sNotALie. Of course but mock should be syntatically and semantically correct isn't it?

Comment: @Srirarm The idea is there, I'm fairly certain that anyone who sees this gets the point. I didn't copy/paste exactly what was in my code directly.

Comment: @Alex No more discussions about this needed, Let's consider this as a pseudo code. alright?

Comment: And that's called common sense.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain What would be the point of caching the time locally within this method?

Comment: @Alex I moved my comment to [cHao's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18748882/80274) I explain better there. But the biggest two things is [a expensive get operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16779909/why-is-a-simple-get-statement-so-slow) (be it from a slow data source or struct boxing) or if a varying property like `DateTime.Now` crosses one of the boundaries while it is going down the list of statements it could cause a bug of the incorrect block being run.

Comment: You need to set a strategy. So you have to implement Strategy pattern. By using if/else statements you violate OCP principle from SOLID.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you're really looking for a design pattern, I'd go for the Chain of Responsibility pattern.

Basically your "link" tries to handle the input. If it is unable to handle it, it's passed down the chain until an other link can handle it. You can also define an interface for easy mocking in your unit tests, if you have some.

So you have this abstract class that every link will inherit :

```
public abstract class Link
{
    private Link nextLink;

    public void SetSuccessor(Link next)
    {
        nextLink = next;
    }

    public virtual decimal Execute(int time)
    {
        if (nextLink != null)
        {
            return nextLink.Execute(time);
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And then you create each links with your rules :

```
public class FirstLink : Link
{
    public override decimal Execute(int time)
    {
        if (time > 0 && time <= 499)
        {
            return .75m;
        }

        return base.Execute(time);
    }
}

public class SecondLink : Link
{
    public override decimal Execute(int time)
    {
        if (time > 500 && time <= 999)
        {
            return .85m;
        }

        return base.Execute(time);
    }
}

public class ThirdLink : Link
{
    public override decimal Execute(int time)
    {
        if (time >= 1000)
        {
            return 1.00m;
        }

        return base.Execute(time);
    }
}
```

Finally, to use it, just set every successor and call it :

```
Link chain = new FirstLink();
Link secondLink = new SecondLink();
Link thirdLink = new ThirdLink();


chain.SetSuccessor(secondLink);
secondLink.SetSuccessor(thirdLink);
```

and all you have to do, is call the chain with one clean call:

```
var result = chain.Execute(object.Time);
```

Comment: Didn't realize I hadn't selected an answer for this, but I think Chain of Responsibility fits nicely in this situation.

Answer (score 15):

There is a not so famous pattern called '**Rules Pattern**'

The idea is that **everything is extracted into an object** and **let it handle its own job**. You will have **each class for each rule** that you defined which is your condition statement, e.g. ***(object.Time > 0 && <= 499)***

```
public class RuleNumberOne : IRules
{
   public decimal Execute(Oobject date)
   {
      if(date.Time > 0 && date.Something <= 499)
         return .75m;
      return 0;
   } 
} 

public class RuleNumberTwo : IRules
{
    public decimal Execute(Oobject date)
    {
        if(date.Time >= 500 && date.Something <= 999)
            return .85m;
        return 0;
    } 
} 

public interface IRules
{ 
  decimal Execute(Oobject date);
}
```

Therefore, on your class that used to look like this

```
if(object.Time > 0 && <= 499)
{
     rate = .75m
}
else if(object.Time >= 500 && <= 999)
{
     rate = .85m
}
else if(object.Time >= 1000)
{
     rate = 1.00m
}
else
{
     rate = 0m;
}
```

Will now be,

```
private List<IRules>_rules = new List<IRules>();
public SomeConstructor()
{
    _rules.Add(new RuleNumberOne());
    _rules.Add(new RuleNumberTwo());
}

public void DoSomething()
{

    Oobject date = new Oobject();

    foreach(var rule in this._rules)
    {
        Decimal rate = rule.Execute(date);
    }
}
```

The idea here is that once you get nested if conditions, it would be harder to read the condition statements and its hard for the developer to make any changes. Thus, it separates the logic of each individual rule and its effect into its own class which follows the rule Single Responsibility Pattern.

**Some considerations are**
1.) Read only
2.) Explicit order
3.) Dependencies
4.) Priority
5.) Persistence

Again, consider using the Rules Pattern when you have a growing amount of conditional complexity and your application's requirements warrants it.

You can customize it if you want don't want it to return decimal or something but the idea is here.

Comment: This is referred to as Strategy Pattern:

http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx

Also to note: It's not something I can use a foreach on the statements. I have to determine which strategy to use, and only use one. I put an edit in the OP to explain what i'm doing a little better.

Comment: Strategy Pattern is different from Rules Pattern.

Comment: If that's the case then define the rules to return a condition which rules should be executed then instead of doing foreach you do FirstOrDefault on the list of rules to determine which implementation you want to call. Something like _rules.FirstOrDefault(x => x == something)

Comment: As implemented, this will always call all rules, therefore the returned value will always be that of the *last* rule only. So it would appear the "Chain of Responsibility" answer is better.

Comment: this will run all items in the list. This is not a good idea. if you have list of 100 items, it will loop through all of them.

Answer (score 5):

You only need to check one endpoint of the range.  The other one is implied by your actually being at that point in the code, since the earlier conditions were false.

```
if (obj.Time <= 0) {
    rate = 0.00m;
}

// At this point, obj.Time already must be >= 0, because the test
// to see if it was <= 0 returned false.
else if (obj.Time < 500) {
    rate = 0.75m;
}

// And at this point, obj.Time already must be >= 500.
else if (obj.Time < 1000) { 
    rate = 0.85m;
}

else {
    rate = 1.00m;
}
```

It would be better to make the more common end of the scale the one you check first, for readability and performance reasons.  But it'll work either way.

Comment: +1, this is what I was going to post, however one other change I would suggest is cache the result of `obj.Time` at the start to a local variable and check against that. If `obj.Time` is a large struct or a property with a expensive cost to read it could improve performance. (also if Time is a changing property like `DateTime.Now` you could cross a boundary while you are iterating over the `if` statements)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: That would be better.  I was debating whether to do it here; i didn't want to change things so much as to obscure the main point.

Answer (score 3):

Using a map:

```
var map = new[]
{
    new { Rule = (Func<Oobject, bool>) ( x => x.Time > 0 && x.Something <= 499 ), 
          Value = .75m },
    new { Rule = (Func<Oobject, bool>) ( x => x.Time >= 500 && x.Something <= 999 ), 
          Value = .85m },
    new { Rule = (Func<Oobject, bool>) ( x => true ), 
          Value = 0m }
};

var date = new Oobject { Time = 1, Something = 1 };
var rate = map.First(x => x.Rule(date) ).Value;

Assert.That( rate, Is.EqualTo(.75m));
```

---

I like the idea of @lll's `Rules Pattern` answer but it has a flaw.

Consider the following test (NUnit):

```
[Test]
public void TestRulesUsingList()
    var rules = new IRules[]{ new RuleNumberOne(), new RuleNumberTwo() };

    var date = new Oobject { Time = 1, Something = 1 };
    var rate = 0m;

    foreach(var rule in rules)
        rate = rule.Execute(date);

    Assert.That( rate, Is.EqualTo(.75m));
}
```

The test fails. Although `RuleNumberOne` was called and returned a non-zero value, `RuleNumberTwo` was subsequently called and returned zero to overwrite the correct value.

In order to replicate the if..else..else logic, it need to be able to short circuit.

Here's a quick fix: change the interface's `Execute` method to return a `bool` to indicate whether to rule should fire and add a `Value` property to get the rule's `decimal` value. Also, add a defulat rule that alwasys evaluates `true` and returns zero. Then change the implementation (test) to get the value of the first rule to evaluate true:

```
[Test]
public void TestRulesUsingList2()
{
    var rules = new IRules[]{ new RuleNumberOne(), new RuleNumberTwo(), 
        new DefaultRule() };

    var date = new Oobject { Time = 1, Something = 1 };
    var rate = rules.First(x => x.Execute(date)).Value;

    Assert.That( rate, Is.EqualTo(.75m));
}

public class Oobject
{
    public int Time { get; set; }
    public int Something { get; set; }
}

public interface IRules
{ 
    bool Execute(Oobject date);
    decimal Value { get; }
}

public class RuleNumberOne : IRules
{
    public bool Execute(Oobject date)
    {
        return date.Time > 0 && date.Something <= 499;
    }

    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return .75m; }
    }
} 

public class RuleNumberTwo : IRules
{
    public bool Execute(Oobject date)
    {
        return date.Time >= 500 && date.Something <= 999;
    }

    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return .85m; }
    }
} 

public class DefaultRule : IRules
{
    public bool Execute(Oobject date)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public decimal Value
    {
        get { return 0; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can go for a format and not a design-pattern in the `if-else` condition;

Generally, if you have `lot of conditions` I prefer `if` than lot of nested `if-else`'s you can opt for something like this;

```
if(condition1){
   return x;    // or some operation
}

if(condition 2){
   return y;   // or some operation
}

return default; // if none of the case is satisfied.
```

Comment: Note, this basically *requires* that each `if` block end in a `return`, `throw`, `break`, etc.

Comment: How can you assume OP is going to return something ? What if he's performing some calculation with `rate` variable?

Comment: I am returning something, however adding all of these additional return statements will not allow for easy maintainability. If for whatever reason in the future we need to add another rate, then it would be adding an additional if statement by this logic which is what Im trying to get away from.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel I have also commented besides the return statement // or some operation.

Comment: @Alex I will try it now I will Little bit refactor also the IF cases

Answer (score 1):

I do not think this is a anti pattern Problem and for code metrics is also oki. The **If** is not nested and not very complex!.
But you might make better for example using **Switch** or you make own class which contains properties IsAgeBiggerThanMax() etc.

---

Switch update:

```
        var range = (time - 1) / 499;
        switch (range)
        {
            case 0:  // 1..499
                rate = 0.75;
                break;
            case 1: // 500.. 999 
                rate = 0.85;
                break;
            default:
                rate = 0;
                if (time == 1000)
                {
                    rate = 1.0;
                }
                break;
        }
```

Testing is a philosophy question we do not know what is this function and what is doing. maybe it can be tested 100% from outside!

Comment: *switch* for range check?

Comment: Sample code with `switch` will be better. I can't figure out how.

Comment: @I4V http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/792582d0-2e36-40e3-873e-2be18337d074/how-to-use-switch-case-for-a-range-of-number

Comment: I have posted before few days this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18664501/c-sharp-nested-if-statements-in-tdd-and-code-metrics

Comment: Yep, This is clever for a fixed range.:)

Comment: Using a switch for a range is definitely unnecessary complexity and makes the code much less maintainable. It's more on the lines of a "hack" to get a switch to work for this situation.

Comment: And it assumes the range breaks down evenly.  If it doesn't, you're just flat-out out of luck.

Comment: @Bobson we are talking about this use case in other use cases there are another approaches and another way of thinking! Look to my answer Switch OR REDESIGN.

Comment: @BassamAlugili - Use case: This exact scenario, except your boss just told you that the `.85m` rate now applies to times down to `400`.  How quickly can you make that change?

Answer (score 1):

I really like Leo Lorenzo Luis's Solution.
But instead of returning the Rate, I would let the Rule do something with it. 
This will respect The S. from the [S.O.L.I.D. Principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29)
and the [Law Of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).

Also, when a class "asks" for a value that is contained into another class, you can identify it as a `smell` called the [data class](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2006/05/code-smells.html). You should try to avoid this.

That being said: I would do two things to polish Leo Lorenzo's solution:

1. Call the right `Rule` without the `for loop`.
2. Executing the behavior requested inside it's associated `Rule` class.

In order to do this, we have to map the `rule` classes with their time range, so they can be accessed directly instead of having to iterate through a loop. You'll need to implement your own Map Object (or List Object, or Collection), overloading the `[] operator` and it's `add` function

so you can add your rules in your map like this for example:

```
ranges.Add(0,500).AddRule(rule1);
ranges.Add(500,1000).AddRule(rule2);
etc..
```

You can see above, there is an Object `Range` that can have an Object `Rule` associated to it. So you could eventually add more than one rule for the same `Range`.

Then, you call it like this:

```
ranges[Object.time].Execute(Object);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a huge amount of "if" or if you want to put this information in a settings file then I would suggest you create a class to store this information.

```
Class
    FromTime
    ToTime
    Value

values.Add(New Class(0, 499, .75));
values.Add(New Class(500, 999, .85));
values.Add(New Class(1000, 9999, 1));
```

Then you loop each items in the collection

```
if(object.Time >= curItem.FromTime && object.Time <= curItem.ToTime)
    rate = curItem.Value;
```

You could always have nullable values or set -1 as infinite.

```
values.Add(New Class(-1, 0, 0));
values.Add(New Class(0, 499, .75));
values.Add(New Class(500, 999, .85));
values.Add(New Class(1000, -1, 1));

if((object.Time >= curItem.FromTime || curItem.FromTime == -1) && (object.Time <= curItem.ToTime || curItem.ToTime == -1))
    rate = curItem.Value;
```

Answer (score -2):

Just do one comparison in each if, and go top-to-bottom with the values:

```
if (Object.Time >= 1000)
    rate = 1.0;
else
    if (Object.Time >= 500)
        rate = 0.85;
    else
        if (Object.Time > 0)
            rate = 0.75;
        else
            rate = 0;
```